# Implicit conversions in C++ addition

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have a question about implicit type conversions in C++. I'm programming for 32bit ARM microcontroller. If simplified I have the following code:

```
int32_t globalTimeValue = 0;
uint16_t previuostTimerValue = 0;

void PeriodicTimeUpdateFunction() {
    uint16_t curValue = someTimer.currentValue; 
    // it's only 16 bit because it's a value of some microcontroller timer

    globalTimeValue += curValue - previuostTimerValue; // this is the row, that I'm interested in
}
```

I have always thought that, `curValue - previuostTimerValue` will be made as `uint16_t` substraction, providing `uint16_t` result including overflow (which is exactly what i need, if timer had overrun), and later it will be implicitly converted to `int32_t` by means of zero extention and addition will be carried out as 32 bit signed operation.

But instead of zero extending the result of the substraction, the compiler only extends `curValue` and `previuostTimerValue`, making sure that they are proper 16 bit values. But later the substraction is carried out as native 32bit operation and substraction result is added as 32bit value to `globalTimeValue`. Thus essentially it's the same as if i would write:

```
globalTimeValue += (int32_t)curValue - (int32_t)previuostTimerValue;
```

Please help me understand, why is my previous understanding incorrect? Why the compiler does not do (curValue - previuostTimerValue) as uint16_t operation with later zero extension to int32_t?

PS: as always, I'm very sorry if this question is already answered - after some search I could not find an answer.

Comment: See [Conversions with arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) and [Integral_promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

Answer (score 1):

> why is my previous understanding incorrect?

Because that's not how the language is specified.

No arithmetic operations are performed on integers that are smaller than `int`. On your system, `int` is presumably 32 bit type. All integers of smaller types are promoted to `int` (if it can represent all values of the smaller type, `unsigned int` otherwise).

If you want to have 16 bit roll-over, you can convert the resulting `int` back:

```
globalTimeValue += static_cast<std::uint16_t>(
                     curValue - previuostTimerValue);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's perfectly clear now. After your reply I have found a ton of confirmation to your words. For a very long time I have been working with 8 bit micros, where my previous wrong understanding seemed to hold (at least except when adding 8+8->16 bits). That's probably the reason it eluded me. Thank you once again.

Comment: And try to stay away from arithmetic operations with unsigned types. They often do not work as intended and the compiler may choose to silently optimize them out completely because you did not understand it well enough!

Comment: @U. W. Thank you for implying that I do not understand anything, but honestly what you are saying seems like complete bull..t. (no offence). Unsigned types work exactly as they are intended, and compiler does not optimize anything out just based on signedness. In my about 15 year experience, If compiler optimizes something out - it's your failure to express the need for this operation result, not signedness problem.

Comment: @user2949923: I wrote "not well enough" and I was not implying anything. i have/had my own problems with unsigned arithmetic, so I try to warn others. For the subtle differences between signed and unsigned, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic in section "Overflows", where you find the sentence "it is completely optimized out by the compiler"